# how to fix The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: javascript, java, php-7, laravel-6, proc-open

I want to upload on hosting but can't upload.

(1/1) LogicException

```
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
in Process.php line 143

at Process->__construct(array(), '/stage/data01/bipaio/public_html', null, null, 60.0)in Process.php line 195
at Process::fromShellCommandline('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1', '/stage/data01/bipaio/public_html')in AddGitInformation.php line 51
at AddGitInformation->command('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1')in AddGitInformation.php line 25
at AddGitInformation->hash()in AddGitInformation.php line 13
at AddGitInformation->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php line 171
```

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved? How is this code related to Javascript or Java?

Answer (score 2):

**In Laravel 6 or higher (*proc_open Error*)**

---

It is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode There is a workaround for this.

Publish flare config file

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

then in

`config/flare.php`

Update this

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],

'send_logs_as_events' => false,
```

Hope It will be work